# comparing two values in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

```
*** Variables ***
${allz}=    checkq

*** Test Cases ***
Test title

      Test IFCOND

*** Keywords ***
Test IFCOND
        Run Keyword If  "${allz}" == "checkq" Log to Console    value is one
```

=============
I get an error saying "Evaluating expression '"checkq" == "checkq" Log to Console' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 1)"

How do I remove the ' before '"checkq"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error adds quotes to help you understand exactly what expression it sees.

To help clarify, I will remove the quotes and replace it with highlighting. The error is telling you that this is invalid syntax: `"checkq" == "checkq" Log to Console`.

So, the problem isn't the single quote, it's that it thinks "Log to Consol" is part of the expression, and the above is very clearly an illegal expression.

The problem is that you only have a single space between `"checkq"` and `Log to Console`, so robot sees both of those as part of the expression.

The solution is to put two or more spaces between the expression and `Log to Console`:

```
Run Keyword If  "${allz}" == "checkq"  Log to Console    value is one
                                     ^^
```